# Convert fetch to use $.ajax in jquery correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, in my code below I have a jquery autocomplete where it works fine on both Chrome and firefox browsers. But, the only thing does not work is on internet explorer 11, so I need help to convert or help me change from `fetch` to `$.ajax` property. Can anyone help me solve this issue? Thanks for the help.

```
  fetch(url, {
    body: data,
    method: "post"
  })
    .then(function(res) {
      return res.text();
    })
    .then(function(text) {
      $("#results").append($(text).find("#textTable"));
      $("#results").append($(text).find("table"));
      $("#results").append($(text).find("#bestTable"));
      $("#clearone").show();
    });
```

Comment: You might consider using consistent indentation when writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier, not only for potential answerers, but for you as well, when we can all see the `{` `}` blocks and their nesting level at a glance, rather than having to carefully pick through each line just to pick up on the logical paths.

Comment: Also, you could just use a polyfill for `fetch`

Comment: I have used polyfill library, but for some reason it stopped working with or without cdn. so, can you help me work with `$ajax` instead of fetch? thank you.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what's going wrong with this code?  That said you have a syntax error in: `function response(event, ui, ) {`

Comment: I don't see that I have syntax error. The code works as I stated.  Can I get what you mean @EvanConrad

Comment: Oh whoops don't mind me. Misread your question.

Comment: @EvanConrad Do you get what i want to accomplish, right?

Comment: @Gary I do. StackOverflow can sometimes be a hard place to get an answer out of, so tips for the future: be sure to _only_ show the pieces of code you want info about. If you throw a whole big chunk of text, I might just skip over it. ‍♀️Similarly, it helps to show something you've tried, that helps people empathize and also gives us an idea of what you're trying to do. But here ya go, have a nice night friend.

Answer (score 3):

> You can try this way.

```
$.ajax({
    url: suburl,
    type: 'post',
    data: { value: "Value1"},
    dataType:"json",  
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error:function(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  method: "POST",
}).done(text => {
    $('#results').append($(text).find('#textTable'));
    $('#results').append($(text).find('table'));
    $('#results').append($(text).find('#bestTable'));
    $("#clearone").show();
})
```

Comment: But, this will work with my code above, right? I will try it out, and let you know. Thank you for the answer. If it works, you know what I will do on stackoverflow. :)

Comment: It should. If it doesn't, try `console.log(text)` to see what it's doing. It might be returning an object, it's been forever since I did jQuery stuff.

Comment: hey @Evan, so the code works but it is not working on internet explorer 11, can you help me with that then I accept your answeR?